# Android Tabbed activity duplicating tabs

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Something weird is happening here, i created an rss feed app with view pager  when i go to **2nd tab** from the **1st tab**, the contents of **3rd tab** are coming to **2nd tab**. When I go to the **1st tab** from **2nd tab**, the contents of **1st tab** are coming to **2nd tab**. something mixing without any logic (or i could not find the logic), why it is happening.. ? is there any way of clearing the current tab before going to next tab ?( don't know this is the correct question i supposed to ask )

[image: take a look]

Here is my code

```
public class datafragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample,container,false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return view;

}

private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final  String tabs[]={"tab1", "tab2","tab3"};
    public sliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment= null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new RssFragment();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new RssFragment1();
                break;
            case 2:
                  fragment = new RssFragment2();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {


       return 3;
    }
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
   }
}

 }
```

After adding the answer

```
 public class datafragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample,container,false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
   // tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
   //     @Override
   //     public void run() {
   //         tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
   //     }
   // });

    **setupViewPager(viewPager);**

    return view;

}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPagerProfile)
{
    SliderAdapter  adapter = new SliderAdapter (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment(), "tab1");
    adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment1(), "tab2");
    adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment2(), "tab3");

    viewPagerProfile.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class SliderAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SliderAdapter (FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Please add your xml file

Comment: Please refer the question @AyushKhare

Comment: With your screenshot, a lot of things became more clear. You might want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315602/weird-tab-behavior-whats-wrong-with-the-adapter

Comment: can you suggest me an answer ?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to have any problem. The problem is how you retrieve your `listView` when you swipe fragments

Comment: list view of java code ?

Comment: see my question again@AyushKhare

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPagerProfile)
        {
            SliderAdapter  adapter = new SliderAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment(), "tab1");
            adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment1(), "tab2");
            adapter.addFragment(new RssFragment2(), "tab3");

            viewPagerProfile.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Custom Adapter:

```
public class SliderAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SliderAdapter (FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to do something on selected fragment, Add listenre:

```
TabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
{
    @Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {
        //Code here for selected fragment 
    }

    @Override public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {

    }

    @Override public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: so i have to create anther adaptor ?

Comment: i did not get your point, can you edit the answer according to my values ?

Comment: just replace your adapter with mine and call setupViewPager in oncreate.

Comment: what about setupViewPager??

Comment: WHERE SHOULD I ADD setupViewPager

Comment: see my last code in the question , i have changed the code

Comment: just see  it is proper or not

Comment: @JaisonJoseph I edited the question, please check it now

Comment: still same problem occur

Comment: why **setupViewPager(viewPager);** in your editing ??

Comment: to add the Fragments to ViewPager Adapter